# The right most tab leaves unnecessary space on the right hand side

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

[image: There is unnecessary space on the right side. Other is the last tab]

I have a tablayout with a viewpager. There are 5 tabs in scrollable mode. The last tab when selected comes at the centre leaving unnecesaary space on the right hand side.

Comment: what is `tabGravity` used for the `TabLayout`?

Comment: Did you set `tab_LAYOUT.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);` ??

Comment: <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tabindicatortextcolor"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
            />

Comment: On strings.xml define the string "others" as "   others". so that some space will be occupied in front which will be appeared as correct space occupied...